# Having trouble integrating Fuel UX with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ngmodel, fuelux

I have been able to successfully integrate the spinbox with AngularJS using the ng-model on the  element. However, I cannot get this to work with selectlist.

I have tried using the [exact sample markup from their documentation](http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#selectlist-usage).

I have tried to add ng-model to the  element, the hidden  and the , none of which seems to work. How would one implement model synchronization with the Fuel UX selectlist using AngularJS?